# Control a Form from another Hidden Form in C#

Tags: c#, forms, controls, hidden

I am working on a client that is sending a request to the server to login and if it's accepted the main window shall be hidden and user will start work on the form 2 named user_form ... and there are 3 buttons available for the users on the user_form ( logout - exit - hide )

I want control them all from the main window which is already hidden ,,,

Here is the code I am working with in main form ... but it's not working as I want.

```
switch (client.LoginInfo.Limited)
{
    case true:
        this.Hide();
        User_Form LF = new User_Form(client);
        LF.AdminControlIsVisible = false;
        DialogResult dr = LF.ShowDialog(this);
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            //logout
        }
        else if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (client != null)
            {
                //hide
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateSystemMessage("No response from the server !!");
            }
            return;
        }
        break;
    case false:
        User_Form LF = new User_Form(client);
        LF.AdminControlIsVisible = false;
        DialogResult dr = LF.ShowDialog(this);
        this.Visible = false;
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            //logout
        }
        else if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (client != null)
            {
                //hide
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateSystemMessage("No response from the server !!");
            }
            return;
        }
        break;
}
```

Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a new thread to run the .net sockets in instead of the main thread .

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to nicely control things that are shown on one form, from another form, maybe this can help you ... (you did not provide the relevant code to give an example using your project, so i just made 2 forms that can change each others background color, without "knowing" each other too much, by using an object that holds the model data and is shared by both forms...)

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MyModelClass model = new MyModelClass();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            model.AnotherColor = model.AColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Control);
            bindingSource1.DataSource = model;
            this.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", bindingSource1, "AColor");
            this.DataBindings.Add("Visible", bindingSource1, "ABool");
            new Form2(model).Show();
        }

        private BindingSource bindingSource1;
        private Button button1;
        private Button button2;
        private Button button3;
        private Button button4;
        private Button button5;

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.bindingSource1 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "Form2 -> green";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 41);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "Form2 -> red";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 70);
            this.button3.Name = "button3";
            this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 23);
            this.button3.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button3.Text = "Form2 -> Visible";
            this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this.button4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 99);
            this.button4.Name = "button4";
            this.button4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 23);
            this.button4.TabIndex = 3;
            this.button4.Text = "Form2 -> Invisible";
            this.button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button4_Click);
            // 
            // button5
            // 
            this.button5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(46, 159);
            this.button5.Name = "button5";
            this.button5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(106, 42);
            this.button5.TabIndex = 4;
            this.button5.Text = "some important form1 button";
            this.button5.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button5.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button5_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.AnotherColor = Color.Green;
            model.doSomething();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.AnotherColor = Color.Red;
            model.doSomething();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.AnotherBool = true;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.AnotherBool = false;
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.someImportantMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        MyModelClass model;
        private Button button4;
        private Button button3;
        private Button button5;
        int callCounter = 0;
        public Form2(MyModelClass model)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.model = model;
            bindingSource1.DataSource = model;
            DataBindings.Add("BackColor", bindingSource1, "AnotherColor");
            this.DataBindings.Add("Visible", bindingSource1, "AnotherBool");

            model.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(model_PropertyChanged);
        }

        void model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = String.Format("PropertyChanged was called {0} times.", ++callCounter);
        }

        private BindingSource bindingSource1;
        private Button button2;
        private Button button1;
        private Label label1;
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.bindingSource1 = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.button4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 41);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 3;
            this.button2.Text = "Form1 -> red";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 12);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 2;
            this.button1.Text = "Form1 -> green";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 231);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(181, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.label1.Text = "PropertyChanged was called 0 times.";
            // 
            // button4
            // 
            this.button4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 99);
            this.button4.Name = "button4";
            this.button4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 23);
            this.button4.TabIndex = 6;
            this.button4.Text = "Form1 -> Invisible";
            this.button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button4_Click);
            // 
            // button3
            // 
            this.button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 70);
            this.button3.Name = "button3";
            this.button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(127, 23);
            this.button3.TabIndex = 5;
            this.button3.Text = "Form1 -> Visible";
            this.button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
            // 
            // button5
            // 
            this.button5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(154, 164);
            this.button5.Name = "button5";
            this.button5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(94, 40);
            this.button5.TabIndex = 7;
            this.button5.Text = "some less important button";
            this.button5.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button5.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button5_Click);
            // 
            // Form2
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button5);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button4);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button3);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form2";
            this.Text = "Form2";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.bindingSource1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.AColor = Color.Green;
            model.doSomething();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.AColor = Color.Red;
            model.doSomething();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.ABool = true;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            model.ABool = false;
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("some less important button was clicked ... \nnow calling the same method that's called from form1's important button");
            model.someImportantMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

MyModelClass.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class MyModelClass : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private System.Drawing.Color _aColor;

        public System.Drawing.Color AColor
        {
            get { return _aColor; }
            set { 
                _aColor = value;
                fireChanged("AColor");
            }
        }

        private System.Drawing.Color _anotherColor;

        public System.Drawing.Color AnotherColor
        {
            get { return _anotherColor; }
            set { 
                _anotherColor = value;
                fireChanged("AnotherColor");
            }
        }

        private bool _aBool = true;

        public bool ABool
        {
            get { return _aBool; }
            set
            {
                _aBool = value;
                fireChanged("ABool");
            }
        }

        private bool _anotherBool = true;

        public bool AnotherBool
        {
            get { return _anotherBool; }
            set
            {
                _anotherBool = value;
                fireChanged("AnotherBool");
            }
        }


        public void doSomething() 
        {
            //some function here
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("doSomething() was called"); 
        }

        private void fireChanged(string name)
        {
            var evth = PropertyChanged;
            if (evth != null)
                evth(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        internal void someImportantMethod()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("some important mehod, that is usually called from a button in from1");
        }
    }
}
```

---

edit:
if you want to trigger other actions on a form, you can also define your own events on the model class and fire them just like `PropertyChanged`

the class that consumes your event should simply register an event handler, like Form2 here does for updating the call counter

---

edit2: changed example code to show hiding forms and relocating code from button_click  handler to seperate method

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you are trying to do, one simple way would be that the forms you wnat controlled have public fonction that when called influence the form. You would then need to pass the instance of those forms to the form that controlls (usually in the constructor). You could then call those fonctions from the controller form and therefore affect the controlled forms.

Example :

```
public class ControlledForm : Form 
{
    //...        

    //This founction will affect the form
    public void DoSomething(int Params)
    {
    //Affect Form
    }

    private void SomethingEventHandler() //function that calls the new form and hides this one
    {
        //Give the construction this (the instance of the form) in parameter
        ControllerForm newControllerForm = new ControllerForm(this);
        newControllerForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}

public class ControllerForm : Form
{
    //Constructor that receives the instance of the controlled form in parameter
    public ControllerForm(ControlledForm CF)
    {
        _ControlledForm = CF;
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    private ControlledForm _ControlledForm;

    private void SomethingElseEventHandler() //Function that modifies the controlled form
    {
        //This will effectively affect the form
        _ControlledForm.DoSomething(12);
    }    
}
```

I don't if that's answers your question, but that's how I tackled the problem since I stumbled upon it.

Comment: you didn't understand me, i mean that i have 2 forms ( form1, form2 ) i want to hide form one and show form 2 but i need to handle 3 buttons in the hidden form (form1) i mean ( form 1 control the 3 buttons which is in form2 ) and 2 of those buttons are getting the form1 is shown and close form 2 .. that's all .

Comment: Ha, then you would need to make public functions in your hidden form and manually subscribe them to the click events of your buttons (see :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx). You will still need the get the instance of your hidden form in order to so that

Comment: so dose there any simple example ?

Comment: Well thanks i fixed it and i will post the answer now